# Erro ao tentar instalar wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estou tentando instalar o `wordpress` no meu servidor local utilizando `xampp` mas recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Sorry, but I can’t write the wp-config.php file.

You can create the wp-config.php file manually and paste the following text into it.
```

Alguém saberia como contornar o mesmo?

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente, você precisa setar o wp-config.php como 644 or 640.

Se for Linux;

```
sudo chmod 644 wp-config.php
```

Se for Windows.

Botão Direito em cima do arquivo wp-config.php -> Propriedades -> Segurança -> Editar -> Adicionar -> Escreva "Todos" no campo e dê o Ok.

Comment: Não existe esse arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

A mensagem de erro diz que não tem permissão de escrita no arquivo `wp-config.php`.

Adicionando o grupo do Apache `www-data` ao grupo de permissões do diretório `www`:

```
sudo chown -R root:www-data /var/www/html/wordpress-project
```

E adicionando o seu usuário a esse grupo, já resolve o seu problema:

```
sudo useradd -g www-data usuario
```

Comment: Estou utilizando o xampp.

Comment: Certo. O `xampp` pode ser instalado em 3 sistemas operacionais diferentes! Para que possamos ajudar da melhor forma possível, você precisa passar mais detalhes, qual o sistema operacional você usa, por exemplo?

Comment: Uso o `Ubuntu 16.04`.